# WPF Window size Issues

Tags: wpf, window, size, width

I want my app to fit in all screen sizes, hence from Window tag to all Containers/Panels I have set Width="Auto". Have specified MinWidth & MinHeight in window tag.
   Despite all this, my window shows in huge size more big than required. With my chilf window I have set

```
Height="Auto" Width="Auto" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="650"
     WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Loaded="Window_Loaded"  >

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="650">
```

StackPanel is the parent/root of all panels. As you can see the size of stackPanel is al declared as 650, yet on loading the width of the window is 1440.

I call this Child window from the parent window thri ShowDialog(). Same issue is with parent window also.

Can anyone help me know what is going wrong here ! Why it doesn't honor the size mentioned ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Window's property .SizeToContent to "WidthAndHeight".

Comment: With this also the width was more than required. I tried adding a ViewBox on top of all panels, but no difference.

Comment: I removed ViewBox and just added SizeToContent and it shows the required size of the screen. I have 1 form that might grow big for an 8" screen. So,how to add Scrollbar to the mainpanel or any other way to handle the same. I thought of giving MaxWidth & MaxHeight but that again differs from different screen sizes. How can this be handled the best ?

Comment: You can wrap it in a ScrollViewer, and set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Auto (or however you want it set up)

Comment: Thanks KDiTraglia, adding SizrToContent, Viewbox, and ScrollViewer got my results as I wanted to. This would be mangable for any screen size and resolutions. Thanks alot.